# Add different class names to specific nth-childs

Tags: php

I have this code (PHP):

```
<div class="rocksType_DBitems_container">
  <?php
    define ('ACCESS', 1);           
    require_once 'database.php';       
    $db = new Database();           
    $sql = 'SELECT Drn,Src,Tit,Sub FROM Img_Ardosias WHERE Drn > :id';             
    $parameters = array(':id' => 0);
    $results = $db->getArray($sql, $parameters);
    foreach ($results as $index => $result){
      $html = '<div class="rocksType_DBitem">
                 <p>
                 <span class="rocksType_title">'.$result['Tit'].'</span>
                 <br/>
                 <span class="rocksType_subtitle">'.$result['Sub'].'</span>
                 </p>
                 <img class="rocksType_image" src="'.$result['Src'].'" alt="" />
               </div>';
      echo $html;
    }
  ?>
</div> <!-- End of class="rocksType_DBitems_container" -->
```

... that, basically, dynamically creates several divs with image and text inside, in a vertical layout, in which the first 3 divs have different css styles than the rest.

My question is simple: how do I add 3 different classes to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd dynamically created divs (the ones that have class="rocksType_DBitem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define classes you want to add:

```
$classes = array('green', 'blue', 'yellow');
```

And modify your script a little :

```
foreach ($results as $index => $result){
    $classAdd = $classes ? ' rocksType_DBitem_' . array_shift($classes) : '';
    $html = '<div class="rocksType_DBitem' . $classAdd . '">
```

So first 3 divs will have classes 'rocksType_DBitem_green', 'rocksType_DBitem_blue', 'rocksType_DBitem_yellow' + 'rocksType_DBitem' and rest will have only class 'rocksType_DBitem'

Comment: Thank you for the swift reponse. One question though: I need to add those classes and not replace the existent ones. Ex: the 1st item will be: class="rocksType_DBitem rocksType_DBitem_green"

Answer (score 1):

I will add to your code

```
$results = $db->getArray($sql, $parameters);    

extraClasses = array('green', 'blue', 'yellow');
i = 0;
foreach ($results as $index => $result){
  extraClass = '';
  if (i<3) {
      extraClass = extraClasses[i];
      i++;
  }

  $html = '<div class="rocksType_DBitem "'+extraClass+'">
             <p>
             <span class="rocksType_title">'.$result['Tit'].'</span>
             <br/>
             <span class="rocksType_subtitle">'.$result['Sub'].'</span>
             </p>
             <img class="rocksType_image" src="'.$result['Src'].'" alt="" />
           </div>';
  echo $html;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/novapla/public_html/index_pt.php on line 1009** -> which corresponds to the line: **extraClass = '';**

Comment: Yes, @mr.Pavlikov did. Thank you for the contribution (+1 for the help).